# Sitecore Item web API for speicfic Sitecore user

Tags: sitecore

I am working on Sitecore Item Web Api, I have a mulitisite solution and I want to give access of Sitecore Item web api to specific Site as per sitecore user.

For example, I have a demo site and have specific user for this site:

```
uname - test
pass - test123
```

My requirement is this user only can access given site via api not others Is it possible and how?

I am using http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/modules/sitecore%20item%20web%20api/sitecore_item_web_api_developer_guide_sc66-71-a4.pdf document and on page 13 it shows some extra fields for security "Field Remote Read" but in normal solution it's not showing any field like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display the Field Read Remote column you should enable it from the columns options from the ribbon:

[image: Columns Option]

And check the checkbox there:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @nsgocev it works, but i still have problem in security as per website

Comment: @YogeshSharma why don`t you just restrict the read permissions on the content items for the sites (for example Site1/Home) for the user ? So this user will have access only to the items of the site you want him to - not only in the api but globally.

Comment: @YogeshSharma Make sure you set itemwebapi.mode=AdvancedSecurity as I mentioned in my post

Comment: Yes I did this but client don't want that type of security :)

Comment: Ok, understand. Then as nsgocev has suggested, in which case you do not need to worry about this field.

Answer (score 3):

If you cannot see the field from the column list like @nsgocev stated, make sure that "Sitecore.ItemWebApi.config" is present in your include folder and enabled. This config adds the `remote:fieldread` field to the access rights/security editor.

```xml
<accessRights>
  <rights>
    <add name="remote:fieldread" comment="Field Read right for remoted clients." title="Field Remote Read"/>
  </rights>
  ...
</accessRights>
```

Also make sure you set the correct mode to take this field into account (as stated in the documentation) to set up the API correctly.

```xml
<site name="website">
    <patch:attribute name="itemwebapi.mode">AdvancedSecurity</patch:attribute>
    <patch:attribute name="itemwebapi.access">ReadOnly</patch:attribute>
    <patch:attribute name="itemwebapi.allowanonymousaccess">false</patch:attribute>
</site>
```